# Why this while loop will not get stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: python

When x = -1, why doesn't this function get stuck in an infinite loop?

If x = -1, it will return 2.0 as a result.

```
def fun_B(x):
    total = 0
    while 1 + x < 1:
        total = total + x
        x = x / 2
    return total
print(fun_B(-1))
```

Comment: Explain why you think it _should_ be an infinite loop.

Comment: `while 1 + (x < 1):` would be an infitine loop with that call

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem? Why not check in each iteration what `x` contains

Answer (score 4):

Floats have finite precision;  in particular, you can only divide by 2 so many times before you get a value so close to 0 that 0 is the closest approximation. At that point, `1 + 0 < 1` is false.

```
>>> while 1 + x < 1:
...   print(x)
...   x = x / 2
...
-1
-0.5
-0.25
-0.125
-0.0625
-0.03125
-0.015625
-0.0078125
-0.00390625
-0.001953125
-0.0009765625
-0.00048828125
-0.000244140625
-0.0001220703125
-6.103515625e-05
-3.0517578125e-05
-1.52587890625e-05
-7.62939453125e-06
-3.814697265625e-06
-1.9073486328125e-06
-9.5367431640625e-07
-4.76837158203125e-07
-2.384185791015625e-07
-1.1920928955078125e-07
-5.960464477539063e-08
-2.9802322387695312e-08
-1.4901161193847656e-08
-7.450580596923828e-09
-3.725290298461914e-09
-1.862645149230957e-09
-9.313225746154785e-10
-4.656612873077393e-10
-2.3283064365386963e-10
-1.1641532182693481e-10
-5.820766091346741e-11
-2.9103830456733704e-11
-1.4551915228366852e-11
-7.275957614183426e-12
-3.637978807091713e-12
-1.8189894035458565e-12
-9.094947017729282e-13
-4.547473508864641e-13
-2.2737367544323206e-13
-1.1368683772161603e-13
-5.684341886080802e-14
-2.842170943040401e-14
-1.4210854715202004e-14
-7.105427357601002e-15
-3.552713678800501e-15
-1.7763568394002505e-15
-8.881784197001252e-16
-4.440892098500626e-16
-2.220446049250313e-16
-1.1102230246251565e-16
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're encountering a floating point error.

After a very large amount of iterations, x will become so small, that python has a hard time distinguishing it from no change at all essentially.

For instance, after 1000 iterations:

```
x = -1.1665795231290236e-302
```

and:

```
1 + x < 1
>>>False
```

This is just a limitation of programming with numbers.

Comment: It happens in far fewer than 1000 iterations.

Comment: True, hence the "for instance" :p. Just threw a number in there that I *knew* would cause the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Each time this iterates, x gets closer to 0:

```
x -1
total 0
x -0.5
total -1
x -0.25
total -1.5
x -0.125
total -1.75
x -0.0625
total -1.875
x -0.03125
total -1.9375
x -0.015625
total -1.96875
x -0.0078125
total -1.984375
x -0.00390625
total -1.9921875
x -0.001953125
total -1.99609375
x -0.0009765625
...
```

Eventually, x will become so close to 0, that python can't tell the difference, at this point the while loop will break.

Comment: Oops, I mean to say that x will become so close to 0 - edited my answer accordingly